# Git remote add failed

Tags: git, mercurial, git-remote

I tried running

```
$ git remote add -f i175 "hg::https://G.nius.ck@code.google.com/r/gniusck-175/ "
```

and got

```
Updating i175
hg: *** failed to import extension keyring: _type_ 'v' not supported
hg: abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/git-remote-hg", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('git-remote-hg==0.1.1', 'git-remote-hg')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 505, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1245, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git_remote_hg-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/git-remote-hg", line 7, in <module>
    res = git_remote_hg.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git_remote_hg-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/git_remote_hg/__init__.py", line 122, in main
    hg_checkout = HgGitCheckout(git_dir, hg_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git_remote_hg-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/git_remote_hg/__init__.py", line 169, in __init__
    self.initialize_hg_repo()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git_remote_hg-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/git_remote_hg/__init__.py", line 203, in initialize_hg_repo
    self._do("hg", "update", "null", cwd=hg_repo_dir, silent=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/git_remote_hg-0.1.1-py2.7.egg/git_remote_hg/__init__.py", line 177, in _do
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.git/hgremotes/https%3A%2F%2FG.nius.ck%40code.google.com%2Fr%2Fgniusck-175%2F%20'
error: Could not fetch i175
```

How do I make it correctly fetch?

(Note: I tried the mailing list, but it is buggy and it wouldn't accept my error report. If this doesn't work, I am trying Linus Torvald.)

Comment: Trying Linus Torvalds for something that isn’t part of Git in the first place? Well, good luck.

Comment: If you do mail Linus Torvald and get a response, be sure to post it here as an *answer*. ;)

Comment: @minitech The git remote helper is integrated into git know (or at least I don't think it is a separate program.)

Comment: You can ask author of original bridge, @felipec is here, on SO. From my POV, you have (unrelated to GIt or bridge) permission problem inside (local Git) repository - `git remote add` **must** create file, but can't do it

Comment: Try a slightly slower: add remote without -f option, check remote before fetch with show

Comment: Oh it is separate? I did not know.